# Exporting users from specific OUs

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm writing a PowerShell script to list of all our users in our active directory. Within our main OU we have sub OUs, there are two things i'm struggling with.

First being I need to exclude specific sub OUs from this report I'm not sure how to do this. The second problem I am having is i'd like to have the OU they are within included within the report, at the moment I get a output like this:

```
DisplayName   CanonicalName

Kanye West    ad.test/All Users/People that have left/Kanye West
```

I'd to exclude the "ad.test/All users" and "/Kanye west". So all I'd like to output is the SUB OU name.

Here is what I have written so far:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=All Users, DC=ad,DC=test" -Properties DisplayName, CanonicalName | select DisplayName, CanonicalName | Export-CSV c:\experiment.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for the editing @Matt

Comment: No problem. If you stick around look at what I did to get an idea of what you could do later. We are all here to help.

Comment: Just took a look, thanks this will be helpful for my next post :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the output from one OU, I'd suggest going to that location first.

```
Import-Module activedirectory
Set-Location 'AD:\OU=People that have left,OU=All Users,DC=ad,DC=test'
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties DisplayName,CanonicalName | Select-Object DisplayName,CanonicalName | Where-Object CanonicalName -ne 'Kanye West' | Export-CSV C:\Experiment.csv
```

---

Add:

```
Import-Module activedirectory
Get-ADUser -Filter 'CanonicalName -ne "Kanye West"' -SearchBase 'OU=People that have left,OU=All Users,DC=ad,DC=test' -Properties DisplayName,CanonicalName |
  Select-Object DisplayName,CanonicalName |
  Export-CSV C:\Experiment.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for but I would get a list of all OU's/Containers you want to search first in an array and then search all of those for objects.

```
# The OU you want to start searching from
$baseOU = "OU=All Users, DC=ad,DC=test"
# Any OUs that you do not want to be searched
$ouOmits = "All users","Kanye West"
# Get all sub OUs and OU of $baseOU minus any OU that is in the omission list
$ousToSearch = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase $baseOU -Filter *  | 
    Where-Object{$_.name -notin $ouOmits} | 
    Select -Expand DistinguishedName
```

If you only have PowerShell 2.0

```
$ousToSearch = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase $baseOU -Filter *  | 
    Where-Object{$ouOmits -notcontains $_.name} | 
    Select -Expand DistinguishedName
```

So that will get all OU's you want to search for. So now lets loops through them and get all of the objects we actually want.

```
$ousToSearch | ForEach-Object{
    Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $_ -SearchScope OneLevel -Properties DisplayName,CanonicalName
}
```

Normally the search is recursive. To make sure our omits work as intended then we limit the search to just the OU's we are asking for.

Comment: It's a shame `-SearchBase` doesn't accept a `String[]` type.  Just to add-on, Filter Left, Format Right.  OP wants to exclude certain OUs and users.  `-Filter 'DistinguishedName -notmatch "^CN=.+,.*,OU=All\sUsers" -and CanonicalName -ne "Kanye West"'`

Comment: Shame indeed. I found my way to be cleaner and if his actual use case has more OU's then it might be simpler to go about it like this. I hated using regex for DN's when there are objects that have this information.

Comment: I was just basing my filter example based on what my own environment's Get-ADUser gives me. I don't work with AD super often.

Comment: Wow thanks for this, looks complicated haha. Thank you for writing this out for me, i'm trying to figure out where I put in the OUs i want it to search? I'm getting the following message when I try to execute:

You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator at line 4 char:27.

I'm assuming when it says value expression this is the OU i should enter? I have tried replacing the `-notin` with an OU name but no luck. Any clues on what I should try next? Thanks again guys

Comment: I shall assume you have PowerShell 2.0 then since -notin is a 3.0 operator. @Navee I had made some edits to help clarify and get past your error.

Comment: Hi matt, sorry for the late reply. Changing the command as suggested worked for me, so I am using 2.0. The script is running about 40% how I want to, but i'm going to try and figure out what the problem is. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Good to hear. If you consider this solved I suggest marking the answer that best helped you with a green checkmark beside that answer. You can also upvote any content you find useful.